# Android - AdView missing required XML attribute 'adSize' when trying to add admob

Tags: android, admob

My layout xml says missing XML attribute 'adSize'. here is my layout xml
Can anyone help me to figure out what I am doing wrong here. I tried severel methods that are described for this type of questions, but no luck.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/close" 
            android:onClick="dbcheck2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="startShowMeaningService"
            android:text="@string/startapp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AdMob in android "AdView missing required XML attribute 'adSize' "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7185335/admob-in-android-adview-missing-required-xml-attribute-adsize)

Comment: clean build project.

Comment: @Harry , I did but still not working

Comment: I assume library is referenced properly. Try ctrl+a, ctrl+d,ctrl+z and clean build.

Comment: Thanks, I restarted everything and it works now

Answer (score 2):

you have missed the namespace

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: but in this tutorial they ask to use this namespace 
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" , I tried your one also but still not working

Comment: @Chann the new one require this xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: @Chann Accept the answer for others to refer it